# Partition by consecutive dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns. X being the unique identifier. I want to get the row number when I partition by column Y only if Z is in consecutive order. For example, I have this table

```
   X    Y   Z 
   A    1   1-jan
   A    1   2-jan
   A    1   3-jan
   B    3   1-jan
   B    3   2-jan
   A    1   5-jan
```

The result should look like this:

```
   X    Y   Z      rn
   A    1   1-jan  1
   A    1   2-jan  2
   A    1   3-jan  3
   B    3   1-jan  1
   B    3   2-jan  2
   A    1   5-jan  1
```

The code I am using right now:

```
  select X, Y, Z, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Y order by Z) as rn
```

I am getting this as my result (This is not the result I want):

```
   X    Y   Z      rn
   A    1   1-jan  1
   A    1   2-jan  2
   A    1   3-jan  3
   B    3   5-jan  1
   B    3   6-jan  2
   A    1   5-jan  4  <---- Column Z is not 4-Jan therefore it should be the not be row 4. It should be a new row 1
```

Comment: If you provide the DDL+DML (or a db fiddle) you make it much easier to answer cos we don't have to type all your data in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that column Z is a date column, you could try the following:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X, GRP ORDER BY Z) AS RN
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Z), Z) AS GRP
  FROM table_name
) T
ORDER BY X, Z
```

If the Z column datatype is not date, then you may generate the groups of consecutive values as the following:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X, GRP ORDER BY Z) AS RN
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Z, 0, CHARINDEX('-', Z)) AS INT) - 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Z, CHARINDEX('-', Z)+1, LEN(Z)), CAST(SUBSTRING(Z, 0, CHARINDEX('-', Z)) AS INT)) AS GRP
  FROM table_name2
) T
ORDER BY X, MONTH(SUBSTRING(Z, CHARINDEX('-', Z)+1, LEN(Z))+' 1 1'), CAST(SUBSTRING(Z, 0, CHARINDEX('-', Z)) AS INT)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y6s3Pyj1).

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create data that can be used to partition your table.

The below uses LAG() to determine if a row is a "new partition", then SUM() OVER () to propagate that flag forward and make a "partition id", then finally uses ROW_NUMBER() with that identifier.

```
WITH
  gap_marker AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    IIF(
      LAG(z) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z)
      =
      DATEADD(day, -1, z), 
      0,
      1
    )
      AS new_date_range
  FROM
    yourTable
), 
  date_range_partition AS
(
  SELECT
    gap_marker.*,
    SUM(new_date_range) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z)   AS date_range_id
  FROM
    gap_marker
)
SELECT
  x, y, z,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y, date_range_id ORDER BY z)   AS rn
FROM
  date_range_partition
```

Alternatively, you could calculate an amount to deduct from the current `rn`, to reset to `1` when a date is skipped.

```
WITH
  enumerated AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z)   AS rn,
    DATEDIFF(
      day,
      LAG(z) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z),
      z
    )
      AS delta
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  x, y, z,
  rn - MAX(IIF(delta = 1, 0, rn - 1)) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z) AS rn
FROM
  enumerated
```

Finally, you could use DATEDIFF() if your rows are always whole days apart. Window functions can be used to work out what you should compare the current row against, and avoid ROW_NUMBER() altogether.

```
WITH
  check_previous AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    IIF(
      LAG(z) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z)
      =
      DATEADD(day, -1, z), 
      NULL,
      z
    )
      AS new_base_date
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  x, y, z,
  DATEDIFF(
    day,
    MAX(new_base_date) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z),
    z
  ) + 1
    AS rn
FROM
  check_previous
```

Demo of all three; https://dbfiddle.uk/K8x8gOqh

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem using postgresql. Extract the logic and convert into your sql dialect.

DDL statement:

```
create table demo
(
x varchar(10) not null,
y int not null,
z date)

insert into demo(x,y,z) values
('A',1,'2022-01-01'),
('A',1,'2022-01-02'),
('A',1,'2022-01-03'),
('B',3,'2022-01-01'),
('B',3,'2022-01-02'),
('A',1,'2022-01-05');
```

query:

```
with base_data as (
select x,y,z,
row_number() over(partition by x,y) as sno
from demo
)
,staging_data as  (  
select x,y,z, z - coalesce(lag(z) over(partition by x,y),z-1::INT) as diff
from base_data)
select 
x,y,z,row_number() over(partition by x,diff)
from staging_data
```

z-1::INT - instead use date_add(z,-1)- Hope this change will work in sqlserver

output:

```
x|y|z         |row_number|
-+-+----------+----------+
A|1|2022-01-01|         1|
A|1|2022-01-02|         2|
A|1|2022-01-03|         3|
A|1|2022-01-05|         1|
B|3|2022-01-01|         1|
B|3|2022-01-02|         2|
```

Comment: PostgreSQL answers on SQL Server questions get downvoted. ROW_NUMBER() without ORDER BY gets downvoted. LAG without an ORDER BY gets downvoted. PARTITION BY x is also mistaken as the OP describes x as a unique identifier, and doesn't use it in their code.